# wget index.html file showing blank on Google Chrome after loading fine for 1 or 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, wget

new here.

I used wget to download a website files and when i use live view of the index.html on Google Chrome the webpage loads and you see it for 1 or 2 seconds and then it goes blank? Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Used wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent

Opened the index.html file and used Live Preview in VS code.

Webpage showed for 1 or 2 seconds perfectly then went blank.

Answer (score 0):

> Webpage showed for 1 or 2 seconds perfectly then went blank.

This suggests that some JavaScript is executed after page is loaded. Firstly determine if there is `<script>` tag in `index.html` by opening it in text editor. If it is present disable JavaScript in your browser and then open `index.html` using it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the webpage going blank after a few seconds when using `wget` to download the website and live preview it in VS Code could be due to missing or incorrectly linked JavaScript, CSS files, or other dependencies. `wget` might not fully capture dynamic content or resolve relative paths correctly. Check for missing resources, broken links, and server-side rendering. Consider using a local web server to serve the downloaded files for better results.